# After surrounding a function (which returns a password) with print, why can the function not repeat itself?

Tags: python

I have a simple program:

```
import secrets
import string

class simple_password:
    def __init__(self, length: int, characters: str) -> None:
        self.length = length
        self.characters = characters

    def generate(self, iterations):
        for p in range(iterations):
            output_password: str = ''
            for c in range(self.length):
                output_password += secrets.choice(self.characters)
            print(output_password)


var = simple_password(20, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123467589')
var.generate(2)
```

It generates passwords depending on length, characters given and the number of times a password should be generated.

When I generate the password, it will print it out like so:

```
0monm0typ7a5pnkmq7l5
0os1q66zcwueudt72ijt
```

However when i generate the password, i would like it so that it ***doesnt*** print out the passwords when the program is run.

Therefore, i **remove** the `print(output_password)` and replace it with `return output_password`. This way, you can still generate a password but not show it when you run the program. If you want to see it however, I have to surround it with `print(var.generate(2))`.

My **problem** is that now it cant generate multiple passwords for some reason. For example, if i use the statement `print(var.generate(2))` (which should output 2 random passwords) i only receive one. No matter the iterations i have provided in the .generate function, i always only receive **one** password.

Why is this happening and how can i solve it? Many thanks.

Comment: The problem isn't the `print` around it, the problem is that `return` terminates the function and, well, *returns* the value to the caller.

Comment: Do you know what `return` does? It terminates the function immediately, and flow of execution returns to the place that called the function in the first place. If you return inside a loop, you're still doing exactly that - you're terminating the function prematurely, and so the outer for-loop never has a chance to advance to the next iteration.

Comment: oh i understand now. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding all password to a list, and then returning. Returning stops the function!

```
import secrets

class simple_password:
    def __init__(self, length: int, characters: str) -> None:
        self.length = length
        self.characters = characters

    def generate(self, iterations):
        res = []
        for p in range(iterations):

            output_password: str = ''
            for c in range(self.length):
                output_password += secrets.choice(self.characters)
            res.append(output_password)
        return res 

var = simple_password(20, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123467589')
print(var.generate(2))
```